# How to place a plane over an ARTrackedImage - Unity3D AR Foundation

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, image-recognition

I am tracking images with my AR-App and whenever an image got detected there should be a plane overlaying the tracked image.
The plane should have the same dimensions and rotation as the image.
I've already tried using [this code snippet](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/blob/0fbf6dad4544d7b34c790705a3cbab4c448fe711/Assets/Scenes/ImageTracking/TrackedImageInfoManager.cs#L60-L90) but retrieving the image's children's transform yields an error because the image doesn't have any children. Following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkzMFNmvums&t=951s&ab_channel=GDGJohannesburg) wasn't successful either.

Anyone got an idea on how to get the ARTrackedImage's plane information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by instantiating a plane-prefab with the tracked image's transform as parent and modified its localScale to fit the image's size.